# Task lifetime Child vs parent

Tags: c#, task

I'm familiar with Task and Threads and I already know [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Child");

    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.Default);

    Task.WaitAll(t);
    Console.WriteLine("Parent");
}
```

Does `Console.WriteLine("Child");` get called regardelss the call of `Task.WaitAll(t);` In other words: Is there a way to execute ALL started subtasks without `waiting` them (and not killed as soon as the parent finishes execution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C# program will terminate as soon as there are no foreground threads running.  `Task.Factory.StartNew` uses the thread pool thread to do its work, and thread pool threads are all background threads, not foreground threads, and as such don't prevent the entire program from terminating.

If you want to ensure that the entire program doesn't terminate you need to make sure you have at least one foreground thread running, this means either having the additional work you do in the `Task` you create do its work in a foreground thread, rather than a background thread (which is appropriate, if you want that work to prevent the application from terminating), or it will mean waiting in your one existing foreground thread for the others to finish.

Comment: And what if I use Threads and set `thread.IsBackground = false;`?

Comment: @Emaborsa You absolutely shouldn't do that for a thread pool thread.  It's specifically designed around having background threads, and you shouldn't disrupt that; it's very likely to end up causing problems.  If you're creating your own new threads, then they'll be foreground threads by default.